# Access subkeys in multi-dimensional JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

This is really a JavaScript question, as it involves iterating through the elements of a multidimensional js object and interpreting how to use the Firefox console's representation of that object.

Using d3.js/dc.js, I have two line charts. When the user clicks on a dot point in one chart, I need to identify the same point on its companion chart. Both charts use a similar X axis, a date series. The dates will correspond exactly, so the nth datapoint on chart 1 will correspond to the nth datapoint on chart2 - so when the user clicks on chart 1, I have the data from the data point they just clicked on and I want to grab the "y" data from the same datapoint on chart 2 (identifiable by having the identical "x" datapoint on the x-axis).

I am attempting to iterate through the multidimensional JavaScript object (representing the datapoints on the d3.js line chart #2) and I am unsure how to access the value I need.

This loop:

```
lineChart.on('renderlet', function(lineChart) {
    var allDots = lineChart.selectAll('circle.dot');
    allDots.on('click', function(d) {
        var dot2find = d.x;
        for (var key in allDots) { //<=== THIS LOOP
            //at the moment, I am just cycling through chart 1 to find its own date
            if (allDots.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(allDots[key]);
                //if (this_x_val == dot2find) alert('Found It');
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
[circle.dot, circle.dot, circle.dot, (etc, all the 600+ data elements)]
```

[image: Array of circle.dot chart objects]

When I look inside one of those circle objects, I see this (in Firefox console):

[image: Inside one circle.dot object, in the Firefox console]

When I open that first ***__data__*** object in Firefox console, I see the elements I need to access: the x (date) value:

[image: I need the x and y values from the line chart, revealed here]

So, in my for loop above, how do I access the `x` (date) value and the `y` (numeric) value in each of those circle.dot objects?

Code Example:

```js
var startDate = new Date("2011-11-14T16:17:54Z");
var currDate = moment(startDate);
var cf = crossfilter([{date: startDate, quantity: 1}]);
AddData();

var timeDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.date; });
var totalGroup = timeDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.quantity; });

var lineChart1 = dc.lineChart("#line-chart1")
    .brushOn(false)
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]))
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(totalGroup);
var lineChart2 = dc.lineChart("#line-chart2")
    .brushOn(false)
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]))
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(totalGroup);
var lineChart3 = dc.lineChart("#line-chart3")
    .brushOn(false)
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]))
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(totalGroup);

dc.renderAll();

lineChart1.on('renderlet', function(lineChart1) {
    lineChart1.selectAll('circle.dot').on('click', function(d) {
         alert('Chart One: X-axis (Date): ' +d.x+"\n\n"+ "Y-axis (Value): "+d.y);
         //How would I add the corresponding y-axis datapoint values for charts 2 and 3?
    });
});

d3.selectAll("circle.dot").on("mouseover", function(){
var thisDatum = d3.select(this).datum();
  d3.selectAll("circle.dot").filter(d=>d.x == thisDatum.x && d.y == thisDatum.y).attr("fill", "firebrick");
}).on("mouseout", function(){
 d3.selectAll("circle.dot").attr("fill", "teal")
})

for (var nn=1;nn<6;nn++){
 setTimeout(function(){
    AddData();
    lineChart1.x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]));
    lineChart2.x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]));
    lineChart3.x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]));
    dc.renderAll();
  },1000);
}

function AddData(){
    var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    currDate = currDate.add('month', 1);
    cf.add( [{date: currDate.clone().toDate(), quantity: q}]);  
}
```

```css
#line-chart3{margin-bottom:10px;}
.msg{font-family:Arial,Helvetica;font-size:1.2rem;color:brown;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.1/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<link href="http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="msg">Click a data point in chart 1:</div>
<div id="line-chart1"></div>
<div id="line-chart2"></div>
<div id="line-chart3"></div>
<div class="msg">Click on a data point in chart 1 -- an alert messagebox should pop-up with the corresp. datapoint values from all 3 line charts.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any kind of loop.

To get the properties associated with the clicked element, just use:

```
d3.select(this).datum()
```

In your case, if you want the `x` property:

```
d3.select(this).datum().x
```

Here is a demo to show you how to do it. In this demo, I'm drawing two SVGs with the same data. When you hover over one circle, it paints the circle at the other SVG which has the same `x` and `y` properties:

```js
var data = [{x:20, y:30},
{x:40, y:60},
{x:20, y:40},
{x:10, y:90},
{x:70, y:20},
{x:60, y:90},
{x:30, y:90},
{x:90, y:10}];

draw("#svg1");
draw("#svg2");

function draw(selector){

var width = 250,
    height = 250;

var svg = d3.select(selector)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([30, width - 10]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([height - 30, 10]);
 
var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle");
 
circles.attr("r", 10)
 .attr("fill", "teal")
 .attr("cx", d=>xScale(d.x))
 .attr("cy", d=>yScale(d.y));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,220)")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);

}

d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function(){
var thisDatum = d3.select(this).datum();
  d3.selectAll("circle").filter(d=>d.x == thisDatum.x && d.y == thisDatum.y).attr("fill", "firebrick");
}).on("mouseout", function(){
 d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", "teal")
})
```

```css
#svg1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg1"></div>
<div id="svg2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, very well written answwer but it doesn't quite address the question I am asking *(admittedly using too many words).* In your example, you are applying a style to all datapoints with a certain X value across all charts. How would I mod this to collect the "y" data from each of the corresponding datapoints in, say, two other charts, while identifying which chart each datum comes from?

Comment: For example, I have chart1, chart2, chart3. User clicks on datapoint with x = [Feb 10, 2016 at 3:15pm] (std js date) in chart1. I need to return an array or object with the y values from that same [Feb 10, 2016 at 3:15pm] datapoint on charts 2 and 3, something like this: {"chart2":"1705", "chart3":"645"}

Comment: Well, this question is a bit different from the one in your post. In that case, simply get the value with a getter and filter the data array.

Comment: Yes, in hindsight I realize I buried the real question *"when the user clicks on chart 1, I have the data from the data point they just clicked on and I want to grab the data from the same datapoint on chart 2 (identifiable by the date)."* under too much pre-amble and explanation. I understand filtering the data array, but cannot envision how to get the value with a getter.

Comment: This is a getter: `d3.select(this).datum().date`. If there is any `date` property in the data, you get that date when you click the element.

Comment: Try to create a running code, as I did in the snippet, and it will be easier for anyone trying to answer your question. Right now we don't know your data structure, which makes the guessing game quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

To access a nested property, such as the `'x'` property of the `'__data__'` property of the `allDots[key]` object, you would simply chain property dereferences:

```
allDots[key].__data__.x
```

OR

```
allDots[key]['__data__']['x']
```

(or any mixture thereof)

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I updated the question to be more clear. The Firefox console has a specific way of revealing object properties, and that **__data__** object is from the Firefox console, not from the chart's data set. Weird, I know, but you helped me to realize that I must be clear that this object is specific to the Firefox console. Thanks! *BTW and FWIW, I usually prefer Chrome and its DevTools, but in this instance the Firefox console is much more helpful. Provides info that Chrome's console just doesn't offer.*

Comment: `__data__` is what d3 uses internally to bind the data to an element.  It's not generated by the browser.