# Using .filter() in d3.js to return data from corresponding x-axis point on multiple charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

This question builds [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150936/access-subkeys-in-multi-dimensional-javascript-object/).

Using d3.js/dc.js, I have three (or more) charts. All have the same x-axis (a date series), so the nth datapoint on any chart will correspond exactly to the nth datapoint on the x-axis of the other charts.

When the user clicks on a dot point in one chart, I need to get the "y" data from the same point on the other 2+ charts and return an array or object or string with the chartID/y-datum from the other charts, something like this:

```
{"chart1":"30","chart2":"50","chart3":"10"}
```

Here is an example borrowed from Gerardo Furtado's answer to the above-referenced question. How would I modify Gerardo's example to return the datapoints from each chart?

```js
var data = [{x:20, y:30},
{x:30, y:60},
{x:40, y:40},
{x:50, y:90},
{x:60, y:20},
{x:70, y:90},
{x:80, y:90},
{x:90, y:10}];

draw("#svg1");
draw("#svg2");
draw("#svg3");


function draw(selector){

var width = 250,
    height = 250;

var svg = d3.select(selector)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([30, width - 10]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,100])
    .range([height - 30, 10]);
 
var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle");
 
circles.attr("r", 10)
 .attr("fill", "teal")
 .attr("cx", d=>xScale(d.x))
 .attr("cy", d=>yScale(d.y));

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,220)")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);

}

d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function(){
var thisDatum = d3.select(this).datum();
  d3.selectAll("circle").filter(d=>d.x == thisDatum.x && d.y == thisDatum.y).attr("fill", "firebrick");
}).on("mouseout", function(){
 d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", "teal")
})
```

```css
#svg1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg1"></div>
<div id="svg2"></div>
<div id="svg3"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have several different data sets, I'll modify the answer I wrote in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150936/access-subkeys-in-multi-dimensional-javascript-object) so we can have different y values.

First, let't put all data in an object. That way, we can access the different data sets later:

```
var dataObject = {
    data1: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 30
    }, ...
    }],
    data2: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 70
    }, ...
    }],
    data3: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 10
    }, ...
    }]
};
```

Then, we call the draw function:

```
draw("#svg1", dataObject.data1);
draw("#svg2", dataObject.data2);
draw("#svg3", dataObject.data3);
```

So, to get what you want, in the mouseover...

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
    var thisDatum = d3.select(this).datum();
    findPoints(thisDatum);
})
```

We call this function:

```
function findPoints(datum) {
    var myObject = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        myObject["chart" + i] = dataObject["data" + i].filter(e => e.x === datum.x)[0].y;
    }
    console.log(myObject)//use return instead of console.log
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var dataObject = {
    data1: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 30
    }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 60
    }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 40
    }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 90
    }, {
        x: 50,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 60,
        y: 90
    }, {
        x: 70,
        y: 90
    }, {
        x: 80,
        y: 10
    }],
    data2: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 70
    }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 60
    }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 80
    }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 50,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 60,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 70,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 80,
        y: 90
    }],
    data3: [{
        x: 10,
        y: 10
    }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 20
    }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 40
    }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 90
    }, {
        x: 50,
        y: 80
    }, {
        x: 60,
        y: 70
    }, {
        x: 70,
        y: 50
    }, {
        x: 80,
        y: 50
    }]
};


draw("#svg1", dataObject.data1);
draw("#svg2", dataObject.data2);
draw("#svg3", dataObject.data3);


function draw(selector, data) {

    var width = 200,
        height = 100;

    var svg = d3.select(selector)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([30, width - 10]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 100])
        .range([height - 30, 10]);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    circles.attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "palegreen")
        .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.x))
        .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.y));

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(2);

    svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,70)")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
        .attr("class", "yAxis")
        .call(yAxis);

}

d3.selectAll("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
    var thisDatum = d3.select(this).datum();
    findPoints(thisDatum);
    d3.selectAll("circle").filter(d => d.x == thisDatum.x).attr("fill", "firebrick");
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill", "palegreen")
})

function findPoints(datum) {
    var myObject = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        myObject["chart" + i] = dataObject["data" + i].filter(e => e.x === datum.x)[0].y;
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject))
}
```

```css
#svg1, #svg2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg1"></div>
<div id="svg2"></div>
<div id="svg3"></div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, Gerardo. Grateful once again for an excellent demo.

Comment: No worries. Is that what you want? I see that you are struggling with this for some time now...